# Operand should contain 1 column(s) sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Please help me in solving this particular sql problem. I tried every way possible but still can't get it right.

```
insert into service_enrollments (device_id, channel_id, enrollment_status, created_at, updated_at) 
select(devices.id, devices.channel_id, 'registered', bas_tokens.created_at, bas_tokens.created_at) 
from devices, bas_tokens 
where devices.id not in (select device_id from service_enrollments) and devices.channel_id is not null;
```

When I run just the where command I am getting correct results. Thanks :)

Comment: where command correct  what is the meaning of this

Comment: When i run the where command like this then it is giving correct result, 
select * from devices where id not in (select device_id from service_enrollments) and channel_id is not null.

Comment: do not use select (), use select without brackets/parens

Answer (score 1):

You miss the join:

```
insert into service_enrollments (device_id, channel_id, enrollment_status, created_at, updated_at) 
select devices.id, devices.channel_id, 'registered', bas_tokens.created_at, bas_tokens.created_at
from devices join bas_tokens on <condition>
where devices.id not in (select device_id from service_enrollments) and devices.channel_id is not null;
```

And remove the brackets arround the selected columns. See the fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/767671

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried this before but, was showing the same result.

Comment: @user1932914 What is the result?

Comment: Same as above, Operand should contain 1 column(s)

I changed the from line to 
from devices join bas_tokens on devices.id=bas_tokens.device_id

Comment: @user1932914 can you provide some sample data? Or best is a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: Do you wanna know the database schema or the data stored in database for these 3 tables?

Comment: @user1932914 both

Comment: @user remove the brackets arround the selected columns: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/767671 too

Answer (score 1):

Join is one problem and select should not have to start with `(`

```
insert into service_enrollments (device_id, channel_id, enrollment_status, created_at, updated_at) 
select devices.id, devices.channel_id, 'registered', bas_tokens.created_at, bas_tokens.created_at 
from devices, bas_tokens 
where devices.id not in (select device_id from service_enrollments) and devices.channel_id is not null and devices.id = bas_tokens.id;
```

And you have taken 2 tables and there should be a joining condition else it will do a cartesian product.

Comment: Solved my problem by applying your solution. Thanks for the help!!

Comment: @user1932914 Kindly mark it as selected if it solved your problem, this will help others. Thanks.